# Angle product formula for trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry

We a have a formula for angle sum
\begin{align*}
\sin (x\pm y) &= \sin x\cos y \pm \cos x\sin y\\
\cos (x\pm y) &= \cos x\cos y \mp \sin x\sin y\\
\tan (x\pm y) &= \frac{\tan x\pm \tan y}{1\mp \tan x\tan y}
\end{align*} 
My question: Is there any formula for
\begin{align*}
\sin (x\cdot y) &= ? \\
\cos (x\cdot y) &= ? \\
\tan (x\cdot y) &= ?
\end{align*}

If there is no such a formula, why(what makes it so hard to find one)?

Comment: Because... It does not make sense to multiply two angles (but angle × scalar make sense). And, degree or radians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "special" formula.

There is the formula that comes from the angles sum:

$\sin(ab)=\sin\left(\frac{ab}2+\frac{ab}2\right)=\sin\left(\frac{ab}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{ab}2\right)+\cos\left(\frac{ab}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{ab}2\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{ab}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{ab}2\right)$

And likewise to the others

---

You asked to add this part:

First of all you need to know 3 important facts: $$(1):a^{bc}=(a^b)^c\\(2):i=\sqrt{-1}\implies i\cdot i=-1\\(3):e^{in}=\cos(n)+i\sin(n)$$

Now let's define 2 natations: $$\Re(a+ib)=a\\\Im(a+ib)=b$$

With those 5 things we can get a (not really) nice formula:

$$\sin(ab)=\Im(\cos(ab)+i\sin(ab))=\Im\left(e^{iab}\right)=\Im\left((e^{ia})^b\right)=\Im(\left(\cos(a)+i\sin(a)\right)^b)\\
\cos(ab)=\Re(\cos(ab)+i\sin(ab))=\Re\left(e^{iab}\right)=\Re\left((e^{ia})^b\right)=\Re(\left(\cos(a)+i\sin(a)\right)^b)\\
\tan(ab)=\frac{\sin(ab)}{\cos(ab)}=\frac{\Im(\left(\cos(a)+i\sin(a)\right)^b)}{\Re(\left(\cos(a)+i\sin(a)\right)^b)}$$

For example:

$$\sin(2a)=\Im((\cos(a)+i\sin(a))^2)=\Im(\cos^2(a)+i2\cos(a)\sin(a)+i^2\sin^2(a))=\Im((\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a))+i(2\cos(a)\sin(a)))=2\cos(a)\sin(a)$$

Comment: Now, it becomes more complicated.

Comment: @marya what do you mean by that? It is just matter of simplifying: $\cos(ab)=\cos(0.5ab+0.5ab)=\cos^2(0.5ab)-\sin^2(0.5ab)$ and $\tan(ab)=\tan(0.5ab+0.5ab)=\frac{2\tan(0.5ab)}{1-\tan^2(0.5ab)}$

Comment: @marya if you meant a formula that separate $a$ and $b$ we do have such a thing but it is very complicated, you need understanding in complex number for it, I'll add it to my answer if you want it

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a formula that separate $a$ and $b$. Please add it to your answer.

Comment: @marya I add it with example, it is complicated thing so if you don't understand something ask

Comment: You are right, it is complicated(Complex analysis).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69282/discussion-between-marya-and-holo).

Comment: No, I was was wondering if there is some generalization of double angle formula.

Comment: @marya then no, there is no formula. and the reason is very straight forward: it makes no sense, if it did then it doesn't matter if you use radians or degree but $(90\cdot 180) deg\ne (\frac\pi2\cdot\pi)$(it is not equal most of the times). What I gave you is a formula for angle times a scalar

Answer (score 0):

No there are not.

Of course you can always treat the final product as a sum.

**Example**

$$\sin(30\cdot 5) = \sin(150) = \sin(60 + 90)$$

Of which you know the rule.